# Behaviour of bubbles on the surface of a liquid

Tags: electromagnetism

When you observe a group of very small bubbles on the surface of say, a cup of coffee, you can see that when the bubbles get close enough to the edge of the glass, the get attracted to it and eventually collapse into it.

Can anyone explain this phenomenon ? Is it due to some form of electromagnetic attraction ?